# Manually associated models, Rails can't understand data from second model. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created 2 models: users and friends. User has_many friends and friend belong_to Users.

In both models I manually set the foreign_key to = uid. Therefore I assume that when I look for current_user.friends, it should list all the friends who have a friend.uid = current_user.uid. However this is not the case.

I believe it might have something to do with my definition of current_user.

My definition of current_user is in my sessions_helper as:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

Notice the session[:user_id]. When I personally sign in, my user_id is 1.

I notice that when I pull `<%= current_user.friends>` in the home view it returns a blank array, which is odd, because I can see in the SQLite database that there is currently 1 user, whose uid is 12345 and there are over 100 entries in the friends model whose uid is also = 12345. Therefore I expect over an array of over 100 friends. Looking into my server's log it shows:

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =? LIMIT 1 <-[0m [['id',1]]`
`SELECT "friends".* FROM "friends" WHERE "friends"."uid" =1 LIMIT 30 offset 0`

This is important because notice that it is looking for friends.uid =1. I'm assuming it is associated with the session[:user_id] but I can't understand why it doesn't look for the `current_user.uid` despite me associating specifically the `uid` as the foreign_key in both tables.

What am I doing wrong?

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid
   has_many :friends, :foreign_key => "uid"
```

Friend model

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :friendid, :name, :uid
   belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "uid"
```

Note that in my sessions controller when Loginin, I use OMNIAUTH and the set the `session[:user_id] = user.id` if that is relevant:
Sessions_controller:

```
def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 
    user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice =>"Signed in!"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across this issue. The solution was to set the primary_key = 'uid' in the user model and :foreign_key =>'uid' in the friend model

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your setup. This statement

```
has_many :friends, :foreign_key => "uid"
```

in the user model, matches `friends.uid` to `user.id`. `friends.uid` is a foreign that is being matched to the primary key of user which is the id column.  This is also same here,

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "uid"
```

You need to set the primary key of user to `uid` if you want this to work.  Is there any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: how do I set the primary key? The reason is just that I already populated the friends db but I can always repopulate it. Can you advise how to set uid as the primary key?

Comment: i suggest you change how your models work instead of changing the rails defaults. it's much easier this way.  what's wrong with using the id as the foreign key?